# C# Delimiter not showing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to concatenate with delimiter the value from datagridview. Unfortunately, I'm lost using string join. Thanks, if someone can correct my mistake.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string message = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Column1"].Value);
        if (isSelected)
        {
            message +=  String.Join(", ", row.Cells["pk_pspatitem"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: the delimiter will only show to separate multiple items. If there is only one then it will not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter will only show to separate multiple items. If there is only one then it will not show.

Try collecting all the values and then using the `String.Join` with the delimiter.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Column1"].Value);
    if (isSelected) {
        values.Add(row.Cells["pk_pspatitem"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
string message = String.Join(", ", values);
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can query it with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/):

```
string message = String.Join(", ", from DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows
                                   where true.Equals(r.Cells["Column1"].Value)
                                   select r.Cells["pk_pspatitem"].Value);
```

---

With [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) in C# 7.0 (comes with Visual Studio 2017)

```
string message = String.Join(", ", from DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows
                                   where r.Cells["Column1"].Value is true
                                   select r.Cells["pk_pspatitem"].Value);
```

Comment: I like your answer the best, but I'd rather see `where (bool)r.Cells["Column1"].Value`. The `true.Equals` is a little awkward.

Comment: @Enigmativity it is very unusual, but in my opinion it's the safest when comparing to object that can be anything including null and DBNull.Value. It does something like `obj is bool && (bool)obj == true` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,0bb4737ad44c98a4

Comment: Fair enough. That does sound like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

[String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to concatenate an array. You're just adding a string to another string. Use the standard concatenation operator, `+`.

```
message += ", " + row.Cells["pk_pspatitem"].Value.ToString();
```

Consider also that this will cause your message to start with a comma, which can be fixed like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(message.Substring(2));
```

Of course, you could convert the rows into an array and then use `String.Join`, but I don't see any value in that.